# How to override war property files from outside the ear during app. startup

Tags: jboss

I have few property files outside the war/ear in some location. Whenever the app is started/re-started, the default property file inside the war should be overridden by those files outside the war. Is that possible in JBoss 6.0.2.GA?

Comment: My guess is those files inside the war/ear have precedence than those outside because that's where the application will look for  them first before venturing outside. So I would rather not include them in the war/ear and just outside.

Comment: @Omoro Okay, but I just want to know, during the explosion of the war/jar into to the temp folder can we override the default property file inside the war by the corresponding file outside the war at some location. I don't want to access the file directly from the location outside the war.